# Why do we need to create a base element class while working on UI in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export class BaseElement {

    constructor(){
        this.element = null; //jquery Object
    }

    appendToElement(el) {
        this.createElement();
        el.append(this.element);
    }

    createElement(){
        let s = getElementString();
        this.element = $(s);
    }

    getElementString(){
        throw 'please override getElementString() in BaseElements';
    }
}
```

why do we need to create this base element class for the UI??

Comment: Are you sure you're using React JS? A React component class will have inheritance like so: `class BaseElement extends React.Component`

Comment: In Reactjs you don't need to use jQuery. That's the whole point of React's virtual DOM.

Comment: i am not sure about the react but i need to do this thing, its the Object oriented programing using ES6

Comment: @KaranKJ ReactJS is an UI library for building web pages. It uses ES6 features. You can refer the ReactJS documentation and blog for more details about ReactJS and what it is trying to resolve in the frontend when we have so many frameworks available in the market. There are courses available in online where you can learn more about ReactJS and its features.

Comment: @KaranKJ Do upvote when you find the answer is the solution which you are looking for in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create any base component for UI. Below is the sample code for creating components.

**Class component**

```
import React from 'react';

export class LoginComponent from React.Component {

  render() {
     return (
       //Your UI code comes here
      )
  }
}
```

**Function Component**

```
import React from 'react';

export default StaticComponent = (props) {
   return (
      //Your UI code here
   )
}
```

Please refer [React Site](https://reactjs.org) for more details.